# does ng-bootstrap support the new feature cards of bootstrap4, please?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I want to use cards and grid layout in my project with angular2 and ng-bootstrap.

Does ng-bootstrap support the new feature cards of bootstrap4, please?

Answer (score 1):

The ng-bootstrap project is hosted at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io and it doesn't have a specific card component. This feature was discussed in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/50 and the conclusion was that there is little (non at all?) advantage of encapsulating cards into a component.

The good news though is that a [accordion](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion) is build on top of cards so it you were planning to use cards to arrange those into an accordion - this is supported.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can see the list of [ng-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/) components at the left sidebar and [card component](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/) aren't there. But, you can use [Angular Material 2](https://github.com/angular/material2), you can see the [component list here](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/components) - they have a [grid-list](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/components/grid-list) and [card](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/components/card) components.

Here is [Angular Material 2 starter guide](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md).

By the way, Angular Material 2 and ng-bootstrap are a work in progress, so keep an eye on both of them. They updated often.

Comment: The questions asks specifically about https://ng-bootstrap.github.io and you seem to be confusing it with another project.

Comment: All the links for Angular Material 2 no longer work. You should update this post for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bootstrap` does not have any component for cards.

But we can use code of [boostrap card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) for same purpose and it will work fine.